# Groovy JsonBuilder print array of objects

Tags: groovy, jsonbuilder

I want to print json like

```
[
  {"ID" : 1, "NAME" : "test1"},
  {"ID" : 2, "NAME" : "test2"}
]
```

Is it possible with jsonbuilder?

Comment: I have found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28206255/groovy-simple-json-array-builder), which was very obvious

Comment: If you found an answer there, upvote it.